# How can I prevent my Android app from stopping when in background?

Tags: android

First of all I want to note that this is my first time working on an Android app, so I know very little about the whole Android app development environment (and still a newbie with programing in general). While testing and experimenting, I made an app that can be started by reading my NFC tag and prints the contents of records in a textView element. Problem is if I start the app like that and then I go into apps overview (I press the square button) the app disappears. With some code for logging events I noticed the app doesn't get destroyed it goes into paused state and then into stopped state right away. When the app is started by tapping its icon (via the launcher I believe is called?) it doesn't behave the same, it doesn't stop when in background and I can get back to it. I want it to act like that no matter what started it. I couldn't find anything about how I could control the life cycle of my app, only answers that explain how to write code that will execute for different states. This is the code that I have:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d("tag", "onCreate called");

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.nfcContentsText);
        textView.setText("Init text");

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Parcelable[] rawMessages = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);

            if(rawMessages != null) {
                NdefMessage[] messages = new NdefMessage[rawMessages.length];
                for(int i=0; i < rawMessages.length; ++i) {
                    messages[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMessages[i];
                }

                textView.setText("NFC tag read. Contents:\n");

                for (NdefMessage message:messages) {
                    NdefRecord[] records = message.getRecords();
                    for (NdefRecord record:records) {
                        if(new String(record.getType()).equals("T")) {
                            String payload = new String(record.getPayload());
                            textView.append(payload + "\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("tag", "onStart called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("tag", "onResume called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d("tag", "onPause called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d("tag", "onStop called");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("tag", "onDestroy called");
    }
}
```

And this is the activity manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc"
              android:host="nfctest"
              android:pathPrefix="/mynfctest" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: "it doesn't stop when in background" -- it will at some point. "With some code for logging events I noticed the app doesn't get destroyed it goes into paused state and then into stopped state right away" -- this is perfectly normal. Any activity will be paused and stopped when it is no longer in the foreground. "I couldn't find anything about how I could control the life cycle of my app" -- that is because, in general, you cannot "control the life cycle".

Comment: @Selvin: Is there a way to get a service to respond to an NFC event? I have not worked with NFC in quite some time, but the setup from the question (particularly the manifest bits) are what I remember, and `NDEF_DISCOVERED` was an activity `Intent`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I understand that the OS will eventually stop and destroy apps when they're not in use and it needs to free resources and I don't mean absolute control over the life cycle of the app, I can tell that's not possible since is the OS's job to handle that, not the app. I don't understand however why would the system decide to stop my app when it is not in foreground if it was started by the nfc intent compared to when it is started by launcher. I want it to stay in the background (paused) so I can return to see the displayed information instead of losing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to this I'd first recommend reading over the [Activity Life-Cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle), you can see how perhaps having your code executed in the onCreate method is affecting what you see when you return the app.

If the app is only paused or stopped in the background then onCreate will not be executed when you return to your app - its probably only calling onStart and/or onResume depending on state.

As a quick test you could try move your code from onCreate to onResume and see what behaviour you get.

If you're wanting to so stuff in the background, then consider looking into [Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) - there is an example on that page.

Implementing a service might be exactly what you're after - the service can process data in the background, and whenever the app springs back into life you can poll the data held by the service.

Comment: "is affecting what you see when you return the app" -- thing is I can't return to the app since is no longer visible. "onCreate will not be executed when you return to your app" -- the app will have to display information that it reads from the tag and send it to a server (haven't done the server part yet), I don't think I care about whether it runs in the background cuz for displaying it wont prolly need to, I just want the user to be able to return to the app to see that information if it switched between apps. Experimenting with onResume sounds like a good idea tho, I'll try it out, thanks.

Comment: So, I've tried writting code for onResume, I tried moving the initial code from onCreate there, didn't fix, I tried leaving initial code in onCreate and saving the information in a String class member inside onPaused, then displaying it again inside onResume, didn't fix. The app still disapears the moment is not in foreground anymore and I can't return to it. (doesn't behave like this when started via tapping the icon, it doesn't disapear then, but also has no good use since I want to use it for NFC reading)